# compiling numpy for python3 for AIX works but import fails

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linker-errors, aix

Has someone had success building the numpy package for AIX6.1 or 7.1?

I downloaded numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz and ran "python3 setup.py install".

After [patching a few source files](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4723) it compiles. However, when I try to import numpy it says:

```
ImportError:    0509-022 Cannot load module /python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so.
       0509-187 The local-exec model was used for thread-local
                  storage, but the module is not the main program.
       0509-193 Examine the .loader section header with the
                'dump -Hv' command.
```

My guess is that it has got some [-fPIC](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVUN6_1.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp11.zlinux.doc/compiler_ref/opt_tls.html) issues?!? I tried "CFLAGS="-fPIC" python3 setup.py install" but with the same result. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again today and it worked. It was indeed an -fPIC issue. I found that "python3 setup.py clean" doesn't clean up all *.so files and so my previous experiments actually never re-build those.
So here's what you need to do:

(0) download the latest numpy source package and unpack it

(1) Make sure Python.h is the first include in the following files

```
numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c
numpy/core/src/umath/test_rational.c.src
numpy/core/src/umath/operand_flag_test.c.src
```

The following don't have include Python.h at all and need to have for them to compile:

```
numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c.src
numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src
numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c.src
```

(2)

```
export CC="gcc -fPIC"
```

(3)

```
python3 setup.py build
```

(4)

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

The python you are using should supply that flag. What does `python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('CCSHARED'))"` print? On a "normal" linux python it should print `[-fPIC]`)