# Numpy failure while installing python(3.6.6) module pandas-0.24.2. on AIX 7.1.0.0 powerpc

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.6, aix

```
Aix ---> 7.1.0.0 (64 Bit)
Python --> 3.6.6
Not able to install module pandas-0.24.2 , 
It is failing while trying to import numpy with the below error message,

 ImportError:        0509-022 Cannot load module $PYTHON_HOME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.16.2-py3.6-aix-7.1.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.so.

Have tried compiling the numpy module from the package source, still it didn't work....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704639/compiling-numpy-for-python3-for-aix-works-but-import-fails#32736358

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12396
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11317
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4723



ImportError: 0509-022 Cannot load module $PYTHON_HOME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.16.2-py3.6-aix-7.1.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.so.
0509-026 System error: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid format
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

1. pip uninstall -y numpy
2. pip uninstall -y setuptools
3. pip install setuptools
4. pip install numpy

Comment: Thanks for the help , setuptools is installed already. I suspect it has something to do with the compatibilty of AIX and the numpy module.